# Jest: How to undo a global mock for certain tests in a file

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to mock Math.random for certain tests and use its original implementation for other tests. How can I achieve this? I've read about using `jest.doMock` and `jest.dontMock`, but I've bumped into a number of issues using them, like:

- I seem to need `require` in order to use `doMock` and `dontMock`, but
  my project only uses ES6 modules for importing modules
- Those functions also have issues taking in a global module like `Math`.
  I get an error when trying to use `jest.doMock("Math.random")`, which
  results in `Cannot find module 'Math' from 'app.test.js'`

I don't necessarily need to use `doMock` and `dontMock` for my tests. They just seemed to be the closest thing I could find in the jest documentation to what I want to achieve. But I'm open to alternative solutions.

My function I want to test inside app.js...

```
export function getRandomId(max) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(max) || max <= 0) {
        throw new TypeError("Max is an invalid type");
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * totalNumPeople) + 1;
}
```

Inside app.test.js...

```
describe("getRandomId", () => {
  const max = 10;
  Math.random = jest.fn();

  test("Minimum value for an ID is 1", () => {
      Math.mockImplementationOnce(() => 0);
      const id = app.getRandomId(max);
      expect(id).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
  });

  test("Error thrown for invalid argument", () => {
      // I want to use the original implementation of Math.random here
      expect(() => getRandomId("invalid")).toThrow();
  })
});
```

Comment: Did you have a look at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreset and https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe("getRandomId", () => {
  const max = 10;
  let randomMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    randomMock = jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random');
  });

  test("Minimum value for an ID is 1", () => {
      randomMock.mockReturnValue(0);
      const id = getRandomId(max);
      expect(id).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
  });

  test("Error thrown for invalid argument", () => {
      // I want to use the original implementation of Math.random here
      randomMock.mockRestore(); // restores the original (non-mocked) implementation
      expect(() => getRandomId("invalid")).toThrow();
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! However, I noticed odd behavior when using `mockRestore` in the second test. Out of curiosity, I wanted to see what `Math.random` returned after restoring `randomMock`. So I placed a `expect(randomMock).toHaveReturnedWith(20)` to make the test fail and view what `Math.Random` actually returned. Oddly, the test failed because `Math.Random` was not called at all.

Comment: If I instead use `mockReturnValueOnce(0)` for the first test and replace  `mockRestore` with `mockClear` in the second test, the issue is resolved. The results  show that `Math.Random` gets called with its original implementation. Do you happen to know why `mockRestore` resulted in `Math.Random` not being called?

Comment: The reason it works with your modification is the `mockReturnValueOnce(0)` which will restore the mock after first invocation of `Math.random`.  
Restoring `randomMock` just means that any subsequent calls to `Math.random()` will not be mocked. but the `randomMock` isn't usable anymore as it has lost it's binding to `Math.random`

Comment: You can check that the answer works as intended by adding a `console.log(getRandomId(42)` in both the tests (after the mocking in the first test and after the restoring in the second test). 
Running the test will always print out 1 in the first test and a random integer (in the given boundaries) in the second case.

Comment: That's good to know! I didn't realize that `randomMock` would lose its binding to `Math.Random` after `mockRestore` is called. I was also able to verify this behavior when running my tests. Thanks for the explanation.